# Smooth Transition of "same" Object across a Pageload

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say I have two simple html pages, both with a div of the same .blabla class.
On one page, the div would be in a different position or have a different size/color/background/etc.

My goal is to have a smooth transition between these two states across the pageload. I'm dreaming of a pure CSS3/HTML5 implementation but I'm guessing that's not quite possible.

My use case is accompanied by a large change of text/content which should really reside on a separate page.

What would be the best way to do this?
I'll accept javascript/alternatives if I must.

Comment: There's no way if you're actually loading different pages. You can use Ajax to pull the content of the next page into the current page, but if you actually load an entirely new page, you won't get your transition.

Comment: So I'll have to pretend with Ajax. Hmm, Thanks, Alright.